# Mongoose: updating a single sub-document issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

**Schema:**

```
    var educationSchema = new Schema({
    schoolName: String,
    startDate: Number,
    endDate: Number,
    degree: String,
    major: String,
    grade: String
});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  education: [educationSchema]
});
```

**Update code:**

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {"_id": req.user.id, "education._id": req.body.id},
  {
    "$set": {
        "education.$": req.body
    }
  }, 
  function(err, edu) {

  }
);
```

Now, if the user only edits the `schoolName` on the `UI` the following happens:

**Pre-save State:**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5878fb4f51ec530358fea907"),
"firstName" : "John",
"lastName" : "Doe",
"education" : [
    {
        "schoolName" : "ABC",
        "startDate" : 1998,
        "endDate" : 2005,
        "degree" : "Bachelor’s Degree",
        "major" : "CS",
        "grade" : "3.5",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5878fbb951ec530358fea909")
    }
]
```

}

**Post-save State:**

```
"education" : [
    {
        "schoolName" : "XYZ"
    }
]
```

Is `$set` not the right operator to use?

Comment: `education.$` references the sub document element. So right syntax to update a field is `"$set": {
        "education.$.schoolName": req.body
    }` or it will replace the referenced element as you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating `education.$` updates the sub-document. If you want to update only the schoolName you must use `education.$.schoolName`.

Change your update code to:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {"_id": req.user.id, "education._id": req.body.id},
    {
        "$set": {
            "education.$.schoolName": req.body
        }
    }, 
    function(err, edu) {

    }
);
```

**EDIT:** (*update any field sent through req.body*)

```
const update = {};

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(req.body).forEach(key => {
    update['education.$.' + key] = req.body[key];
});

User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {"_id": req.user.id, "education._id": req.body.id},
    {
        "$set": update
    }, 
    function(err, edu) {

    }
);
```

Comment: I took schoolName as an example, Users may edit/change any field. What if they changed schoolName and startYear?

Comment: @kmansoor I have edited my reply to suit your requirement of updating any key that comes in through the request body.